# Order not being created on first submit, but it on second

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, quote

I have a strange issue and am looking for advice on how to debug it. Certain orders are not being created on the first submit, but are being created if you hit submit again and it's capturing payment twice. It also removes inventory after the first time, even though no order is created, often resulting in items saying they are out of stock.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot orders not being created after payment has been processed?

Comment: Check in browser console if there is some action where you click on place order in the first time, check if he call well a controller or not, check also if the button not disabled, maybe also you have some JS function disable/enable which there is a class or Id in common